Keycloak access token login
I am trying to forward auth with traefik and keycloak yet when I provide access token to my request I get returned the keycloak login page, how can I make keycloak accept bearer access token or is it outside of keycloak or am I not getting the value of keycloak it would be dumb if i had to login at every request.
I have tried many settings yet no sucess.
